# The use of the definite article with the names of bridges and zoos in American English

Tags: american-english, definite-article, zero-article, proper-nouns

Do the names of bridges and zoos take the definite article in American English? The sources I've explored so far seem to be somewhat contradictory to this question. Maybe someone could suggest the link to a reliable source I've failed to find?

P.S. In British English, as far as I know, they usually do use "the" before the names of bridges; the exceptions are: Tower Bridge, London Bridge, Westminster Bridge, and Waterloo Bridge. With zoos, it's not clear at all.

Comment: This is too broad without specific examples (so add some using articles). But I think the usage of articles is too localized to make set rules. For example, spoken usage of Southern California freeways uses an article (the 405), while in Northern California they do not (just "Interstate 80").

Comment: @user3169 With highways, parkways, freeways, expressways, and turnpikes, to me, it's clear enough: Unless they begin with a word or letter followed by a number or are just numbers they do take "the" article.

Comment: Fair enough. Back to the bridges, you wrote "they usually do use 'the' before the names of bridges". Some examples of this need to be added to your question. Your examples are proper names in themselves, so no article would be used.

Comment: @user3169 My question is about the American English usage, but if you insist, here are some examples: The Humber Bridge, the Queen Elizabeth II Bridge, the Hungerford Bridge, the Clifton Bridge, etc. I don't think the usual  British usage examples might help to answer my question if you do know the answer, not just try guessing it, and that's that. Thanks for your interest, though)

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch the American part since you gave British examples. Anyway, bridges and zoos I am familiar with in the western US usually use *the*. But I think it is based on accepted usage, not due to some rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples in American English of bridges and zoos:

the San Francisco-Oakland Bay Bridge
the Golden Gate Bridge
the Brooklyn Bridge
the San Diego Zoo
the Bronx Zoo

Generally the article is used.